# Counting the number of strings without consecutive repitition.

Tags: combinatorics

A team is to play $n$ games in a row.  In how many ways could they play this series of games without losing two games in a row.

There are $2^n$ total games to be played.  The number of games without consecutive losses would be $2^N$ - (Number of games with at least one consecutive loss).

I'm having a hard time counting the number of games with at least one consecutive loss.  In particular, I can't think of a way to count the number of games with $m$ consecutive losses.

Could someone provide some guidance?

Comment: We have this question many times on the site.  It is usually posed as a bit string without two $1$s (alternately two $0$s) in a row.  You can search for Fibonacci.  I cited two and the one cited in the closure cites many more.

Comment: @RossMillikan Dope, thanks